# Blurry elements on transform scale, but only when Canvas is present on page

Tags: css, html, canvas

My web application supports Zoom to display better for users with different window sizes. I am doing this zoom by applying on the container:

```
transform: scale(1.4)
```

It works really well, but when I have a canvas element on the page (chartjs.org), not only the canvas, but all elements become blurry. If I hide the canvas with display:none; then all elements become crisp again. I have searched all over for a solution and tried many CSS styles with no success.

Can someone  indicate some tests I could make to have this working?

To simulate this, go to http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart (there are canvas charts on the page)  and add style transform:scale(1.5) to the body, all elements will be blurry, not only the canvases.

Comment: Could be a bug, could be a direct consequence. Canvases are coded with their width and height as a real integer number, and cannot use percents, ems, and scalable decimal values the way other HTML elements can; the code behind them generates an actual output bitmap with exactly that many pixels. So, this could be a consequence of trying to scale the end result. (My best guess is that having a canvas on the page then changes the manner in which it's rendered together with other elements)

Comment: Just `scale`-ing one element shouldn't blur other elements on the page so you have some odd interaction going on there. But, you haven't given us enough info to help you. Please provide html & css pared down to [**minimally**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) show the blurring problem.

Comment: edited with a way to simulate the problem

Comment: Odd thing indeed. Though I noticed that when you change the `canvas.style.display = "block"` (to all canvas)  the zoom worked fine for the other elements. Canvases were "inline-block". This is one answer that will be found in the spec.

Comment: fwiw, I can't repro on my mac

Comment: @Kaiido, Looking further into it I am getting very inconsistent results, sometimes the zoom is fine, then it loses resolution. If I zoom 5* its works fine,but if I step up to 5 zoom 2, then 5 it scales pixels. If set the canvas to display:none then to display:block and its is correctly scaled again. From what I can work out it is the CSS grouping properties that are forcing Canvas and other DOM element to be flattened, then transformed together. See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#grouping-property-values

Comment: when I use transition property for transform, it apparently does not blur too.